# .htaccess rule redirect all pages except a few provided ones

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


RewriteRule ^aanbiedinginformatie$ aanbiedinginformatie.php
RewriteRule ^algemenevoorwaarden$ algemenevoorwaarden.php

RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^disclaimer$ disclaimer.php
RewriteRule ^faq$ faq.php
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
RewriteRule ^informatie$ informatie.php
RewriteRule ^inloggen-bedrijven$ inloggen-bedrijven.php
RewriteRule ^inloggen-consument$ inloggen-consument.php
RewriteRule ^nieuws$ nieuws.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)-nieuws$ bekijknieuws.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-persbericht$ persbericht.php?id=$1&bedrijf=$2
RewriteRule ^persberichteninformatie$ persberichteninformatie.php
RewriteRule ^privacy$ privacy.php
RewriteRule ^registreren-bedrijven$ registreren-bedrijven.php
RewriteRule ^registreren-bedrijven-stap-2$ registreren-bedrijven-stap-2.php
RewriteRule ^registreren-bedrijven-stap-3$ registreren-bedrijven-stap-3.php
RewriteRule ^registreren-bedrijven-stap-4$ registreren-bedrijven-stap-4.php
RewriteRule ^registreren-bedrijven-stap-5$ registreren-bedrijven-stap-5.php
RewriteRule ^registreren-consument$ registreren-consument.php
RewriteRule ^vacatureinformatie$ vacatureinformatie.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)-vacatures$ vacatures.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^zoeken-op-(.*)$ zoeken.php?query=$1
RewriteRule ^zoeken-in-(.*)$ zoeken.php?plaats=$1
RewriteRule ^zoeken-q-(.*)-in-(.*)$ zoeken.php?query=$1&plaats=$2

RewriteRule ^(.*)-vacatures-zoeken$ zoekenvac.php?query=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)-in-(.*)-vacatures$ zoekenvac.php?query=$1&plaats=$2
RewriteRule ^vacatures-in-(.*)$ zoekenvac.php?plaats=$1 

RewriteRule ^(.*)-aanbiedingen$ zoekenaan.php?query=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)-aanbiedingen-in-(.*)$ zoekenaan.php?query=$1&plaats=$2
RewriteRule ^aanbiedingen-in-(.*)$ zoekenaan.php?plaats=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)-persberichten$ zoekenpers.php?query=$1
RewriteRule ^persberichten-in-(.*)$ zoekenpers.php?plaats=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)-persberichten-in-(.*)$ zoekenpers.php?query=$1&plaats=$2

RewriteRule ^bedrijven-in-(.*)$ zoeken.php?plaats=$1

RewriteRule ^control/consument$ control/consument.php
RewriteRule ^control/consument-mijngegevens$ control/consument-mijngegevens.php
RewriteRule ^control/consument-wachtwoord$ control/consument-wachtwoord.php
RewriteRule ^control/consument-cv$ control/consument-cv.php
RewriteRule ^control/consument-reacties$ control/consument-reacties.php
RewriteRule ^control/consument-reviews$ control/consument-reviews.php
RewriteRule ^control/logout$ control/logout.php

RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven$ control/bedrijven.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-aanbieding$ control/bedrijven-aanbieding.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-facturen$ control/bedrijven-facturen.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-fotos$ control/bedrijven-fotos.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-kortingscode$ control/bedrijven-kortingscode.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-kortingscode-bewerken-(.*)$ control/bedrijven-    kortingscode-bewerken.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-kortingscode-verwijderen-(.*)$ control/bedrijven-    kortingscode-verwijderen.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-wachtwoord$ control/bedrijven-wachtwoord.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-pakket$ control/bedrijven-pakket.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-persbericht$ control/bedrijven-persbericht.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-persbericht-bewerken-(.*)$ control/bedrijven-   persbericht-bewerken.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-persbericht-verwijderen-(.*)$ control/bedrijven- persbericht-verwijderen.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-profiel$ control/bedrijven-profiel.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-vacatures$ control/bedrijven-vacatures.php
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-vacatures-bekijk-(.*)$ control/bedrijven-vacatures- bekijk.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-vacatures-bewerken-(.*)$ control/bedrijven-vacatures-   bewerken.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/bedrijven-vacatures-verwijderen-(.*)$ control/bedrijven-vacatures-verwijderen.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^control/logoutb$ control/logoutb.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bedrijf.php?q=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^id(.*)-(.*)$ bedrijf.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^branche(.*)-(.*)$ zoekenbranche.php?id=$1
```

What I want, is that all URL's except the one provided above will redirect to `bedrijf.php?q=$1`. I tried excluding but that doesn't work.

So www.site.com/companyname will redirect to bedrijf.php?q=companyname, while www.site.com/contact will redirect to contact.php

How would I do this?

Comment: At first sight it seems to me that you'd need `[L]` flag on all your rules so it stop executing once a rule match.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I added [L] on all my rules but now nothing works anymore. I immediately get redirected to bedrijf.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite rules loop. The entire set of rules keep getting re-applied to the URI until the URI stops changing. Your rule here:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bedrijf.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Has no conditions to prevent a previously rewritten URI from getting rewritten to `bedrijf.php`, since `(.*)` matches everything.

Try adding some conditions to it, like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bedrijf.php?q=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bedrijf.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` solves part of the problem! However as you can see there are a few more rewrite rules who dont have the same filename. So how would I fix that?

Comment: Oh wait! It seems like it's the solution to my problem!